# O que significa "??!??!" em linguagem C?

Tags: c

Certa vez eu vi um código em C com a seguinte linha:

```
...
if (condicao1 ??!??! condicao2){
/* faca algo */
}
...
```

O que significa "??!??!" em linguagem C?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Significa o mesmo que `||`.

Em alguns lugares as pessoas não têm todos os símbolos necessários para programar em C em seus teclados, daí foram criados os trígrafos:

- `??=` = `#`
- `??/` = `\`
- `??'` = `^`
- `??(` = `[`
- `??)` = `]`
- `??!` = `|`
- `??<` = `{`
- `??>` = `}`
- `??-` = `~`

`??!??!` = (`??!`)(`??!`) = (`|`)(`|`) = `||`.

Como mencionado pelo @Laerte, isso caiu em desuso. Hoje em dia só aparece em demonstrações de construções obscuras que se pode fazer em C e C++.

Comment: +1 pela dica clássica pra usar no "Concurso Internacional de Código Obscuro em C"! (http://www.ioccc.org/)

Answer (score 34):

`??!` é um trigrafo equivalente a expressão lógica `||` (ou)

Isso foi inventado porque estes 9 caracteres não fazem parte da **ISO 646**. Assim, para que seja possível programar em qualquer teclado compatível com esta norma, os trígrafos foram criados.

Hoje em dia isso é tão inútil que alguns compiladores (como o próprio GCC) resolveram deixá-los de fora por default. Para habilitar trígrafos no GCC, deve-se passar -trigraphs por parâmetro na linha de compilação.

1. http://renangreinert.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/nao-use-trigrafos.html

Comment: +1 por apontar um caso específico (o GCC não usa por padrão).

Answer (score 33):

O compilador do C, ao ver os caracteres `??!` em sequência, os transforma em `|`.

Se não me engano isso se deve ao fato de que antigamente não eram muito comuns computadores com a tecla <kbd>|</kbd>.

Ou seja, `??!??!` é o mesmo que `||`, o operador binário "OU".