# O que são dígrafos em C?

Tags: c, c++, terminologia, sintaxe

Baseado na pergunta de **[trígrafos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4023)**, o que são dígrafos?

- Por que foram criados?
- Quais são as sequências?
- Os compiladores atuais ainda permitem usá-los?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preferia que não tivesse perguntado :P

Os primórdios dos computadores havia dificuldades para entrar certos tipos de caracteres, então foram criadas essas sequencias de caracteres para representar um outro que realmente deveria ter sido "digitado" ali. Algo semelhante ao que se faz com Unicode hoje em dia em certas situações onde não é possível entrar facilmente o caractere.

De acordo com a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C) seriam estas sequencias:

```
<:  ->  [
:>  ->  ]
<%  ->  {
%>  ->  }
%:  ->  #
```

Trígrafos

```
??= -> #
??/ ->  \
??' ->  ^
??( ->  [
??) ->  ]
??! ->  |
??< ->  {
??> ->  }
??- ->  ~
```

Em geral os compiladores permitem. O [C++ pretende tirar isto da especificação](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3981.html) (acho que já tirou).

Melhor não usar, não tem motivo para isto hoje em dia. Tem um [exemplo aqui](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative).

Comment: Os primeiros parecem avós dos emoticons :)

Comment: Adicione um exemplo @bigown, assim já marco como resposta.

Comment: @Laerte pra que? Não precisa :)

Comment: Nesse concurso o pessoal se supera: [The International Obfuscated C Code Contest](http://www.ioccc.org/)